# Plotly Animated Bar Graph Showing 1 subgroup only in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-python

**Issue:** When I run my code only one status (sub group) shows. The data set is very simple, create date, status and count. I can only think something might be wrong with my data set at this point. Why will it only show one status of the three I have or possibly it works better with a hosted file? It seems to just iterate through the list and not keep each data point in tact until the end. The other code block works fine on github.

Sample of my data set:

```
Status,Create Date,Count
None,17-Apr-12,8
None,30-Apr-12,9
None,23-Aug-12,10
None,3-Oct-12,11
None,9-Jan-13,12
None,29-Jan-13,13
QBOS,31-Jan-13,1
QBDS,1-Feb-13,1
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('qb7.csv')
df.columns = ['Status','Create Date','Count']
includes=['None','QBDS', 'QBOS']
df=df[df['Status'].isin(includes)]
df['Create Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Create Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
fig = px.bar(df,
         x="Status", 
         y="Count",
         color="Status",
         animation_frame="Create Date", hover_name="Status", 
         range_y=[0,8000])
fig.show()
```

``
[image]

Sample of what I want to make:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shinokada/covid-19-stats/master/data/daily-new- 
confirmed-cases-of-covid-19-tests-per-case.csv')
df.columns = ['Country','Code','Date','Confirmed','Days since confirmed']
includes=['United States','Russia', 'India','Brazil']
df=df[df['Country'].isin(includes)]
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
fig = px.bar(df, x="Country", y="Confirmed", color="Country",
animation_frame="Date", animation_group="Country", range_y=[0,35000])
fig.show()`
```

[image]

Comment: Post your sample data from your dataframe

Comment: @bigbounty<bound method NDFrame.head of      Status Create Date  Count
0      None   17-Apr-12      8
1      None   30-Apr-12      9
2      None   23-Aug-12     10
3      None    3-Oct-12     11
4      None    9-Jan-13     12
...     ...         ...    ...
6545   QBOS    6-Jul-20    843
6546   QBOS    8-Jul-20    844
6547   QBOS    9-Jul-20    845
6548   QBOS   14-Jul-20    846
6549   QBOS   23-Jul-20    847

[6550 rows x 3 columns]>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason it doesn't show the intended graph is because of the different number of data. The intended result is achieved when the number of data is aligned.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Status,Create Date,Count
None,17-Apr-12,8
None,30-Apr-12,9
None,23-Aug-12,10
None,3-Oct-12,11
None,9-Jan-13,12
None,29-Jan-13,13
QBOS,17-Apr-12,8
QBOS,30-Apr-12,9
QBOS,23-Aug-12,10
QBOS,3-Oct-12,11
QBOS,9-Jan-13,12
QBOS,29-Jan-13,13
QBDS,17-Apr-12,8
QBDS,30-Apr-12,9
QBDS,23-Aug-12,10
QBDS,3-Oct-12,11
QBDS,9-Jan-13,12
QBDS,29-Jan-13,13
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=',')

import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

# df = pd.read_csv('qb7.csv')
df.columns = ['Status','Create Date','Count']
includes=['None','QBDS', 'QBOS']
df=df[df['Status'].isin(includes)]
df['Create Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Create Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

fig = px.bar(df,
         x="Status", 
         y="Count",
         color="Status",
         animation_frame="Create Date", hover_name="Status", 
         range_y=[0,30])

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by aligned? the Y range being smaller? I have tried different y range sets 30, 100, 200 and it yields the same results for me (the none status only). It may show the QBDS status but won't  keep the others. It only shows 1 status in the legend at a a time and only 1 one chart at a time.

Comment: The range of y-axis is adapted to the sample data.
So, you need to modify the range to `range_y=[0,8000]` according to the real data. I In my environment, each of the three statuses has three moving legends in the case law as well. My environment is plotly:4.9.0+python:3.6.3.